# Listener for MAPKIT current users location change Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Using Apples MapKit API, is there a way to add a listener to determine if the user's current location has changed? Is it also possible to do this in the background while the app is not running?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25451592/5838902) post for listener to determine user's location change. This is not possible to be done in background. In iOS, when your app is not running, it cannot report location or anything.

Comment: Non of those seem to be working. I tried testing if the current location is equal to the location.last. not sure what to do now?