# Current location is not shown perfectly in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, gps, gmsmapview, currentlocation

I have a **GMSMapView** and want to show current location on `GMSMapView`. I have added bellow line in **info.plist** source code -

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Result</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Result</string>
```

My simulated location is San Francisco, CA, USA from xcode.
[Simulated location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlKu7.png)

When I load `GMSMapView` I get location alert.
[Location Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJFPH.png)

But current location always shown San Francisco and all map related Apps on my iPhone's current location change which is always San Francisco though now my phone location should show Dhaka, Bangladesh.
What is the solution ???
I want my current location from my mobile GPS.

Comment: please check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449469/swift-show-current-location-and-update-location-in-a-mkmapview

Comment: You are testing it on simulator or on actual device ? If simulator seems like you added location as San Fransisco hence location is pointing at San Fransisco test it on real device it should be fine

Comment: try adding a gpx file @Ahnaf

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1: Import the this into your controller class 

    import CoreLocation

Step 2: Add this delegate to your class file

    class Your_controller: CLLocationManagerDelegate

Step 3: Declare this above for viewed load

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

Step 4: Add this code to your `viewdidload` method

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      switch (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
          print("No access")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
          print("Access")
      }
    } else {
      print("Location services are not enabled")
    }

Step 5: Add this code below viewdidload method

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
      didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

      let locationArray = locations as NSArray
      let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as !CLLocation
      let coord = locationObj.coordinate

      lattitude = coord.latitude
      longitude = coord.longitude
      print(lattitude)
      print(longitude)
    }

Step 6: add to permission your plist file

Key - "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" 

Value - "This app needs access to your location"

Step 7: run your Application on Hardware Device
```

Comment: thank you, just a minor issue  
    let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as !CLLocation  
should be
    let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation

Comment: Thanks Ravi, +1.  it's really work great:) just want to add some line in location method to add marker which show current location. 
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationObj.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locationObj.coordinate.longitude)
       let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = center
        marker.title = "current location"
        marker.map = mapView
        let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 15) self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
  locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

Answer (score 0):

in your viewDidLoad() add the following for location manager configuration:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Further implement delegates for GMSMapView:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I did it bro, but latitude and longitude always San Francisco

Comment: Is it for the simulator? If I install the app using apk then it will do perfect ?